# Hibernate Java rearranging parentheses in SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I've got a `@NamedQuery` like so

```
select i from MyTable i 
where 
(i.streetId = :streetId and i.cityId = :cityId) 
or 
(i.streetId is null and i.cityId = :cityId) 
or 
(i.streetId = :streetId and i.cityId is null)
```

Somehow Hibernate rearranges the parentheses to

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        mytable0_.id as id1_14_,
        mytable0_.version as version2_14_,
        mytable0_.streetId as streetI3_14_,       
        mytable0_.cityId as cityId7_14_ 
    from
        myTable mytable0_ 
    where
        mytable0_.streetId=? 
        and mytable0_.cityId=? 
        or (
            mytable0_.streetId is null
        ) 
        and mytable0_.cityId=? 
        or mytable0_.streetId=? 
        and (
            mytable0_.cityId is null
        )
```

Why is it doing this ?
(They could be equivalent, but I prefer the simpler where clause)

Current workaround is to write this in native SQL, but I'm just wondering if this is a known issue.

Comment: It's just Hibernate optimisation. The result of your query will be the same.

Comment: The point of Hibernate is SQL abstraction. Hence it may rewrite your queries to more optimized versions. You shouldn't care, as long as the results are exactly the same. There is no need to force native SQL just because you *prefer* the simpler clause. The optimization is happening automatically at runtime, so why bother about it?

Comment: Few things that could be bothering, what if there's a bug in Hibernate as it optimizes my SQL. When a DBA asks what is this SQL that's eating up lots of CPU time, can't quickly cross check since they're different.

Comment: In this particular case I ran a EXPLAIN on my database (PostgreSQL) for both SQL queries, the plan are both identical and uses the first version: (A and B) or (C and B) or (A and D)

Comment: I guess it's fine if you're using pure Hibernate objects (i.e. without NamedQuery or native SQL), you don't care what SQL it generates but abstraction always leaks, that's why Hibernate/Java Persistence have the option of using NamedQuery and native SQL. This is one of the cases of abstraction leak so it's preferable that Hibernate does not make any modification to the SQL. Wouldn't you hate it if you spent some time figuring out the SQL that yields the best execution plan on your particular database then Hibernate simply comes and rewrites it ?

Comment: Is there a flag that disables this behaviour ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 'AND' operation has higher precedence over 'OR' operation in SQL Query execution, hibernate removed unnecessary braces, making the result generated by hiberante query is same as one returned by Named Query. Ex: In SQL Execution:

A and B or C and D or E and F == (A and B) or (C and D) or (E and F).

Comment: But what if I want to do A and (B or C or D)? Hibernate will force it into (A and B) or C or D?

Comment: Hibernate will send the query as A and (B or C or D) only, since A and (B or C or D) != (A and B) or C or D.

Answer (score 2):

Guided by the responses this is what I figured out

Imagine

```
A is streetId = :streetId 
B is cityId = :cityId
C is streetId is null
D is cityId is null
```

My original SQL is

(A and B) or (C and B) or (A and D)

Hibernate's version is

A and B or (C) and B or A and (D)

Since AND has precedence over OR, let's reimagined using MULTIPLICATION for AND and ADDITION for OR

A * B + (C) * B + A * (D)

That's equivalent to

```
A * B gets evaluated 
C * B gets evaluated
A * D gets evaluated
and getting their results added
```

Equivalent to 
(A * B) + (C * B) + (A * D)

Which is exactly my original SQL

Answer (score 0):

Because people may stumble upon this and wonder if, in spite of the query design limitations, it's possible to redesign the query above, consider taking the following subquery approach:

```
select i from MyTable i 
where 
i.id in (select i1.id from MyTable i1 
                           where i1.streetId = :streetId 
                                 and i1.cityId = :cityId) 
or 
i.id in (select i2.id from MyTable i2 
                           where i2.streetId is null 
                                 and i2.cityId = :cityId) 
or 
i.id in (select i3.id from MyTable i3 
                           where i3.streetId = :streetId 
                                 and i3.cityId is null)
```